# What is the private key in RSA?

Tags: rsa, public-key

I'm new to cryptography and I have a doubt: I read some pages a bit different definition for the RSA private key:

In [1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1713/calculating-private-keys-in-the-rsa-cryptosystem) - `(n, d)`

In [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) - `(d)`

In [3](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) - `(n, p, q)`

Should I consider all these answers as correct? I know that if you have `d` and the public key, you have `n` (and `e`), and I know `pq = n` too.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't call $d$ the private key, because it can't decrypt on its own. I'd just refer to it as the private exponent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For private key operations you need at least $n$ (the modulus) and $d$ (the private exponent). The primes $p$ and $q$ let you calculate those – or use [some shortcuts](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2580/13625) for quicker computation – so they also suffice.

In practice RSA keys often include all of those values, to avoid having to compute them as needed and to allow for optimized and unoptimized implementations.

> In [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) - `(d)`

This would not be enough on its own, but the page actually says that the private key includes the modulus.